# Fusionar múltiples polígonos en uno solo y dejando el borde exterior

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de fusionar dos polígonos (departamentos) de Colombia en un solo polígono. Mi objetivo es mantener solo los bordes de ambos polígonos, pero esto no sucede. A continuación adjunto el código. Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

```
download.file("https://github.com/nebulae-co/colmaps/raw/master/data/departamentos.rda","departamentos")
load("departamentos")
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(mapview)

df1 = subset(x = departamentos, depto == "Bogotá, D. C.")
df2 = subset(x = departamentos, depto == "Cundinamarca")

df1@data$id <- df2@data$id <- "a"

df3 = rbind(df1, df2, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
plot(df3)
```

#### Grafico la unión de los dos polígonos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
## Opcion 1
df_12 <- sf::st_as_sf(df3) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup()

plot(as_Spatial(df_12))

## Opcion 2
plot(raster::aggregate(df3))

## Opcion 3
plot(rgeos::gUnaryUnion(df3))

## Opcion 4
plot(st_union(st_make_valid(st_as_sf(df3))))

## Opcion 5
plot(st_as_sf(rgeos::gBuffer(as_Spatial(st_make_valid(st_as_sf(df3))), byid=F, width=0)))
```

#### Mi salida esperada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o comentario

Answer (score 1):

Ciertamente el problema tiene que ver con los polígonos de cada mapa y particularmente como se define cada estado, esto se puede observar así:

```
download.file("https://github.com/nebulae-co/colmaps/raw/master/data/departamentos.rda",
              "departamentos")
load("departamentos")

subset(x = departamentos, depto %in% c("Bogotá, D. C.", "Cundinamarca")) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  mapview()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto, mostramos las dos áreas superpuestas, y si hacemos "zoom" en algunos sectores podemos ver que las dos áreas no tienen siempre los mismos puntos de intersección, por lo que al unir los polígonos, quedarán áreas internas o agujeros ("holes").

Una posibilidad, es realizar la unión de las áreas y quedarnos con el polígono que más puntos tenga, en este caso esto funcionaría bien, pero en otros, tal vez convenga más calcular las áreas y quedarnos con el polígono de mayor tamaño:

```
subset(x = departamentos, depto %in% c("Bogotá, D. C.", "Cundinamarca")) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_make_valid() %>% 
  st_union() -> Centro

main_area <- Centro[[1]][which.max(sapply(Centro[[1]], length))]
plot(st_polygon(main_area))
```

Eventualmente otra cosa que podrías hacer, es remover estas áreas internas, para esto hay algunos paquetes que ya implementan está funcionalidad, por ejemplo `smoothr`:

```
area_thresh <- units::set_units(10, km^2)

subset(x = departamentos, depto %in% c("Bogotá, D. C.", "Cundinamarca")) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_make_valid() %>% 
  st_union() %>% 
  smoothr::fill_holes(threshold = area_thresh) %>% 
  plot()
```

Lo único que se necesita en este caso, es establecer el `threshold` a partir del cual se remueven los huecos, por ejemplo en kilómetros cuadrados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema esta relacionado con el shape. Descargue otro directamente desde la pagina de arcgis y funciona correctamente.

**Pagina de arcgis**

https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/juanespo::departamentos-1?geometry=-107.669%2C-3.045%2C-40.917%2C12.241

**Archivo .zip descarga directa**

https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/2059399a41da4dc0b7683d1822194ae0_0.zip

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)

departamentos <- st_read("E:/Users/Rafae/Downloads/departamentos/b3c7aaf2-9439-4bb6-92e1-aa7b3c401b20202046-1-1gl30yi.xiu1.shp")
#mapview(departamentos)
Centro <- subset(x = departamentos, NOMBRE_DPT %in% c("BOGOTÁ","CUNDINAMARCA")) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% st_make_valid() %>% st_union()

plot(Centro)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]